# How to control the flow direction and fluid level?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation, photorealism

As you can see here, I intend to make a waterfall which is more or less has been successful. However, Once i start playing  the animation the water keeps filling up till the bounds of the domain.

[image]

I want it to fill only till this level, shown below, even if the waterfall(s) continues to flow.

[image]

In addition I want the water to follow this path/direction shown below.

[image]

I want this to look as realistic as possible, so how do I generate the water's froth?

This is my setup file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a box as an outflow object, it will drain the exceeding liquid. After that adjust the inlfow rate to keep the level you need steady.

Comment: Ok, that solve one of the questions...so then how do I control the direction of the flow?

Comment: If you want to make it real let the physics do the job, try tilting the terrain so that the gravity pulls the fluid in the direction you want. If you don't want it to be real but to make the fluid follow an object try using the fluid control type. Other than that, I can't give an answer to the second question, reason for not leaving it as an answer.